# Unable to click on any element in a web page using web driver java

Tags: selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

We are trying to identify an image using  with the name of its image.

```
X path used are :.//a[contains(text(), 'product')]

 Following methods were tried:

1) tried to click using java script executor
2) using Robot
3) using Frame
```

But all throwing error as no such element present.

Could someone help me to identify this element.Its not capturing any element using IDE.

Below are the Html code for the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<frameset framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="NO" rows="67,*">
<frame scrolling="NO" src="markIcons.jsp?sessionId=1274&projectId=15420689&r=376860559" noresize="" name="topFrame">
<frameset cols="*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="NO" rows="*,27">
<frame src="markView.jsp?sessionId=1274&projectId=15420689&r=1565627480" noresize="" name="markView">
<html>
<head>
<frameset cols="*" framespacing="1" border="1" frameborder="YES" rows="*,155">
<frameset rows="*" framespacing="1" border="1" frameborder="YES" cols="35%,53%">
<frame scrolling="AUTO" src="questionhistory.jsp?sessionId=1274&r=402188271#next" noresize="" name="questions">
<frame scrolling="AUTO" src="answers.jsp?sessionId=1274&r=1991810014" noresize="" name="answers">
<html>
<head>
<body vlink="#ffffff" text="#ffffff" link="#ffffff" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" alink="#ffffff" onload="setFocus();" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<p>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="33%" valign="top">
<div align="center">
<a href="javascript:replace('0');">
<img border="0" align="middle" src="http://tcl7srvcert.lowes.com/m2o2/images/product_arbors.png">
</a>
<br>
<div align="center">
</div>
</td>
<td width="33%" valign="top">
<td width="33%" valign="top">
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Share your web driver code which you tried. Tell us which element you tried to click?

Comment: I want to click on image. its in <img> tag.Selenium IDE does not identify any element in this page. Also in XPATH Checker, after clikcing on the image only, am able to see xpath which is not working when running through code.

Comment: using below code.                                                  public void productselection(){
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(), '"+Question+"')]")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//img[contains(@src,'"+answers+"')]")).click();
  //img[contains(@src,'doors')]
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

The element 'a' does not has any text in given html, that is why your xpath did not work. Try following xpath, it should work.

```
//img[contains(@src,'product')]
//img[@src='http://tcl7srvcert.lowes.com/m2o2/images/product_arbors.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

use XPath Checker in FireFox to validate you path before you are using any code
you can also use  Selenium IDE for recording 
i recommend to use css selector but xpath can be good for you 
for java script use this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = null;
 if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript(script);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your element is in a frame, you need to be sure to switch to THAT frame first.  Try:

```
selectFrame   | answers
click         | css=table a[href*='java:replace']
```